# Is there any HTML code example which has all the tags?

Tags: html

I am trying to catch HTML as fast as possible. This sounds bit funny, but I have to. I went through few videos and w3school. Now I want to see how these all HTML tags are used practically. Is there any code example which covers all the HTML tags?

Edit: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Firefox add-on is most useful tool to see all the magic of HTML/CSS/JS. It's powerful. Highly recommended for anyone interested in Web Development.

Comment: Not all tags are used and not all tags are practical to use. Do as someone else has mentioned and constantly look at the source of various sites that you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Firefox add-on is most useful tool to see all the magic of HTML/CSS/JS. It's powerful. Highly recommended for anyone interested in Web Development.

Comment: Take a look at Chrome's built-in dev tools as well.

Answer (score 2):

Load up your favorite websites. Right click -> View Source.

Comment: And if half of the tags are tr and td, try another website.